# I have written simple code using "netbeans 8.0 spring 3.2.7", however I'm getting an error as "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found GlassFish Server 4.1 "

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, netbeans

I have written simple code using netbeans 8.0 spring 3.2.7, however I'm getting an error as

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found type Status report message Not Found descriptionThe requested resource is not available. GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView index()
    {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("message", "This is Spring MVC Testing using Netbeans 8.0");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet  class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello! ${message} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What url are you using to try and access that controller? Whatever it is, the request mapping isn't pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add value parameter to @RequestMapping
like @RequestMapping(value="/")

and change it to 

    dispatcher
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    1